# EL BOTTOM NAVIGATION VIEW SE ESCONDE

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment, bottombar

tengo un bottom navigation view en mi app y tengo un problema porque al cambiar al fragment principal se esconde la mitad del Bottom Navigation View.

**activity_main:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/containerr"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#0f6b96"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/color_state_light"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/color_state_light"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_navigation_basic">

</android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
```

**MainActivity.java**

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(onNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transation = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transation.replace(R.id.container, new Home()).commit();


}
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener onNavigationItemSelectedListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transation = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();


        switch (item.getItemId()){

            case R.id.home:
                transation.replace(R.id.container, new Home()).commit();
                return true;

            case R.id.ofertas:
                transation.replace(R.id.container, new Ofertas()).commit();
                return true;

            case R.id.contacto:
                transation.replace(R.id.container, new Contacto()).commit();
                return true;

        }


        return false;
    }
};
```

}

**home.xml(fragment principal)(los otros dos están vacios)**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    style="@style/AppTheme1">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textColor="#FFF"/>

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

También os adjunto un par de fotos de lo que me pasa

[image: Fragment 1 (principal)]

[image: Fragment 2]

Comment: Hola STC bienvenido al sitio!, es importante realices el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Además revisa [ask] que te da información para realizar una buena pregunta y de esta forma obtengas buenas respuestas!, un gran saludo!.